# Can an ethernet cable from ethernet server router (32 port) split by two

Tags: router, ethernet, port, cable

I live in third floor of a building where second floor got an ethernet server router with 32 ports (Console Serial Port Switch with Ethernet Control Option) on it (refer image: http://www.networktechinc.com/srvsw-term.html). One of those ports has been wired to a small router on third floor. So I'm planning to split the ethernet cable for two different router using a splitter (refer image: http://www.topmicrousa.com/c5ymff.html). The reason why I'm not directly connect to the server on the second floor is it's pretty expensive to get a long cable and also difficult to wiring due to different floor. I know some ethernet cable splits will not work but this one came from a server with a strong internet connection.

Comment: Is the cable connected to an Ethernet port, or to a serial/console port? Different rules apply, ranging from "with difficulties" to "dear gods no".

Answer (score 0):

Your page is loading dreadfully slowly (I've finished my response and your page still has nothing but the title), I strongly suspect it reflects the quality of the "solution" in question.

The only proper way to split an ethernet connection is with a hub or switch.  By a strict reading of the ethernet spec simply splitting the wire should be impossible but I have seen it happen--albeit at the expense of a very high error rate on the connection in question.

The hubs/switches act as traffic lights for the network, the packets are blind to anything except these lights and will happily run into each other without the signalling.  Of course both packets are lost at this point but TCP/IP copes with this loss and replaces them.  Slowly.  In our case add on a buggy network driver and we had a nice case of data corruption.